# Asking for a new tag att-syntax

Tags: feature-request, stack-overflow, tags, tag-creation

Please, can we have a new tag [att-syntax](/questions/tagged/att-syntax) as opposed to [intel-syntax](/questions/tagged/intel-syntax) that already exists?

Comment: Are there already questions that need the [att-syntax] tag?

Comment: I answered one question a user did using the Intel-Syntax. The question used gcc syntax to keyword asm, and gcc uses AT&T syntax. But the user used a macro intel-syntax to change it, and then a macro att_syntax. He asked help for a intel-syntax. But I'm sure I could help using both syntax for that case. The question in in this link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5397677/gcc-intel-syntax-inline-assembly/5398076#5398076 Thanks for your attention

Comment: There is another case, now specifically about AT&T Syntax. The questioner used other tag because he could not use att-syntax tag. Link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4193827/att-x86-syntax

Comment: Hi there. Can someone give me any update on the process of creating this tag. Thanks. (An answer - as simples as possible - will allow me to close the topic.)

Comment: Related: [Can we please have the \[foo\] tag on SO?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/146949/can-we-please-have-the-foo-tag-on-so)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer: ok, feature requested. Nothing more but close the question.